# Having trouble understanding HardHat deployment

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am trying to deploy my basic smart contract, to SKALE Chaos Testnet network, using hardhat. Below are my codes:

**MESSAGE.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract messageNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("Moralis Mage", "MM") {}

    function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
        public
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

**hardhat.config.js**

```
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')
// require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config()

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: '0.8.9'
      },
      {
        version: '0.8.0',
        settings: {}
      }
    ]
  },
  networks: {
    skale: {
      url: process.env.SKALE_ENDPOINT,

      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    },
    sepolia: {
      url: 'https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/2Uu34p8Xg2cuQqNvnzk6Swu0EsXJ7DWF',
      accounts: [
        `0xdf57089febbacf7ba0bc227dafbffa9fc08a93fdc68e1e42411a14efcf23656e`
      ]
    }
  },

  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      skale: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
    },
    customChains: [
      {
        network: 'skale',
        chainId: parseInt(process.env.CHAIN_ID),
        urls: {
          apiURL: process.env.API_URL,
          browserURL: process.env.BLOCKEXPLORER_URL
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

deploy.js

```
const hre = require('hardhat')

async function main () {
  const HelloSkale = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('messageNFT')
  const helloskale = await HelloSkale.deploy()

  await helloskale.deployed()

  console.log('Album.sol deployed to:', helloskale.address)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

When I finally try to deploy using the following command:

```
npx hardhat run --network skale ./scripts/deploy.js
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid method parameters (invalid name and/or type) recognised

I am totally new to this, so please help me understand what i'm doing wrong.

**Note: All .env variables are set properly**

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `package.json` for version clarification.

Given that you're using ethers version 5.0.0 or higher, and assuming that all environment variables are correctly set and the network is properly configured, the issue might stem from the method used to await the contract's deployment.
The `await helloskale.deployed()` statement returns a BaseContract instance, which might not behave as expected in this context. Instead, you should consider using:

`await helloskale.waitForDeployment()`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it need to check openzeppelin library version.

Openzeppelin library is different according to version.

For example, **Ownable.sol** requires constructor arguments since openzeppelin was updated.
Of course, I m not sure when openzeppelin was updated.
When openzeppelin was updated, many of things were changed.

Before, for customization of ERC20 token, can override **_transfer** function.

After update, it needs to update **_update** function.

Please check **package.json** and openzeppelin library version.
I m not sure exactly.
Anyhow, hope it will help you.